# Custom conda package not available in R after installing from conda

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio, conda, devtools

I have recently created a small [package](/questions/tagged/package) (https://github.com/lc5415/HDATDS) and hosted it in [conda](/questions/tagged/conda) (creating custom conda-recipe and so forth - https://anaconda.org/lucha6/r-hdatds).

**Problem**
Installing the package from [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) works fine but when I install from conda (`conda install -c lucha6 r-hdatds`), open an [r](/questions/tagged/r) session from the terminal and run `installed.packages()`, I cannot see my package listed.

**Reproducible example**
In terminal:

```
conda create -n testPackage
conda activate testPackage
conda install -c lucha6 r-hdatds

#open R session
R
#within R
installed.packages() #list installed packages
```

I would expect to see a package called `HDATDS` (in capital letters) but I see no sign of it. Perhaps there is something wrong with my `meta.yaml` file:

```
package:
  name: r-hdatds
  version: 0.1.1

source:
  git_url: https://github.com/lc5415/HDATDS.git

requirements:
    - r-base
  run:
    - r-base
    - r-dplyr
    - r-ROCR
    - r-tidyr
    - r-e1071
    - r-glmnet
    - r-xgboost

about:
  # user-oriented info to be displayed in anaconda.org
  home: https://github.com/lc5415/HDATDS
  license: MIT
  summary: This package was developed as a learning exercise and also to share
   useful functions for the Computational Epidemiology and Translational Data Sciences
   with my colleagues from the MSc in Health Data Analytics & Machine Learning
  license_family: MIT
```

I believe that if I run `devtools::install_github("lc5415/HDATDS")` from an R session from the [terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal), the package is kept in future sessions but ideally the package should be automatically available from the conda installation.

Appreciate any help in fixing this issue.